# Remove last rows and columns of image with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to remove last rows and columns of my image based on given desired height and width.

For example consider I have a image of size 351x572x3.

I would like to have image of size 350x550x3 i.e I want to remove last row and last 22 columns of my image .

How can i achieve this using tensorflow ?

I know the desired_width and desired_height of image in advance

code:

```
def parse_fn(filename,desired_height,desired_width):
    """Decode the bmp image from the filename and convert to [0, 1]."""
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_bmp(image_string)
    # This will convert to float values in [0, 1]
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_decoded, tf.float32)

    # I want to do convert the image to desired width and height here

    return image
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try `tf.slice()`? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just index into tensors like in numpy. So e.g.

```
image_cutoff = image[:desired_height, :desired_width]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is

```
tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(
    image,
    offset_height,
    offset_width,
    target_height,
    target_width
)
```

For your case,

image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image,0,0,desired_height,desired_width)

[link to the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_to_bounding_box)